# Filter in two related model in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have two model named as `Product` and `Category`. In the products table i have category_id as as a foreign key of categories. Both table have `title` column. I want to search on both title and when it is related to categories table then all products of that category will come in result but when it is related to products table then only those products come which are related to query.

I tried it like :

```
$query = Category::with('products')->select(['products.*']);

if($request->get('q')){
    $query->where(function($query1) use ($request){
        $query1->where('categories.title', 'like', '%'.$request->get('q').'%')
        ->orWhere('products.title', 'like', '%'.$request->get('q').'%');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search on both title, when it is related to categories table then all products of that category will come like this:

```
SELECT `title` FROM `PRODUCTS` WHERE `product`.`category_id` = some id ;
```

and in laravel on behalf of product model:

```
Product::select('title')->where(['category_id', 1 ])->get();
```

if you want to search category and then product on behalf of that category you can do it like:

```
$categoryData = Category::select('id')->where(['title', 'LIKE', '%abc%'])->get();
$productData = Product::select('title')->where(['category_id', $categoryData->id ])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do without left join

```
 $result=Category::when($request->get('q'),function ($query)use($request){

        $query->where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->get('q').'%');
    })
        ->when($request->get('q'),function ($query)use($request){

            $query->orWhereHas('categories',function ($q)use($request){

            $q->where('title', 'like', '%'.$request->get('q').'%');

        });
    })->get();
```